# How I can ontextchange method use in flutter TextForm Field?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

i can have one product Screen here we can show cart Added Product and use can change the product Discount & Price & Quanity.

when it changes on price i have one default product minimum Price the product price is not less than to the minimum price so  when user chnage the price i can check the user added price is not less than to the minimum price .if it is less to the minimum price i set old price other wise user added Price.

how i can solve it?

i can expect i can use focuse change event ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.